# update and upgrade not working in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, repository, 21.10

I cannot install some packages. So, I have tried "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade". These commands do not work, I get "IP not found":

OUTPUT:

```
Ign:1 ttp://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease
Hit:2 ttps://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:3 ttps://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:4 ttps://maven.xwiki.org stable/ InRelease
Hit:5 ttps://maven.xwiki.org stable/ Release
Hit:6 ttp://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release
Hit:7 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:8 ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Ign:9 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Err:12 ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:13 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Ign:14 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:15 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::26 80]
Err:16 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::26 80]
Err:17 ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::26 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'ttp://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have read it can be something with the Ubuntu version. I don't want to upgrade to 22.04 if that means loosing all my files and configurations.

Note: I have delete the letter h in the links to be able of posting this questions (too many links)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Your issue relates to the release being EOL*

Comment: Once a release goes EOL, mirrors & 3rd party providers of packagers are free to *drop* support for it, so you've got whatever packages you had & made allowance for before the EOL date (*which was published at release time so you had warning*).  The main Ubuntu repository just gets moved (see first comment), however country mirrors are *dropped*.

Comment: You've not said if you're talking about a Desktop or Server install, but the *release-upgrade* process does **not** erase your configs or data, and if a desktop system - you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without loss of files too (ie. config changes you made survive, further *manually installed* packages from official Ubuntu repositories get auto-reinstalled too so you don't need to re-install those for Desktop installs).

Comment: It's a server install. I don't have any Desktop. So, the solution would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.00 by a release-upgrade process without losing any data, right? This would solve this problem? How can I do that?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 22.00 makes no sense.  Refer to the standard upgrade instructions for 22.04 *jammyupgrades* doco (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades) and the EOLUpgrades I provided in my first link  (or installing software from an unsupported release on this site)

Comment: @guiverc could you publish an answer so I can select it as correct one?